# How to fix this implementation of Bayesian regularization for ANNs?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, regularization, nonlinear-regression

I have implemented the Levenberg-Marquard algorithm (from Hagan's "Artifical Neural Network Design" -- 2014) for a two layer network with 20 neurons in the hidden layer.

This network can beautifully overfit, therefore, I wanted to implement Bayesian regularization.

Below I explain what I implemented. However, it does not work for me (I cannot reproduce some plots in the book).

**Bad result**

1. The training stops after about 20 iterations, whereas in the book at about 100
2. My inital values for $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ start at about 5 and only rise to about 10, where they should start with order 0.1 and settle at around 0.01
3. $\gamma$ rises from 46 to 58, whereas in the book it drops from 61 to 5

**Question**
What am I doing wrong?

---

In the top right plot of the picture below, the red dots are the training points and the blue ones denote the network response at the latest iteration:

[image: My description -- how does this work -- don't see it ...]

**Manual regularization**
It is worth noting, that when I "manually" apply the 0.01 as regularization value, i.e. $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=0.01$, I observe consistent results.

I implement this by using the "old" Jacobian (for $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)=E_{D}$) to determine the direction of the next step $d\bar{\omega}$.

However, to determine the step size such that $F\left(\bar{\omega}+\texttt{d}\bar{\omega}\right) - F\left(\bar{\omega}\right) < F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)$, I make use of the regularised $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)=E_{D} + 0.01\,E_{W}$.

The picture below demonstrates this and is satisfactory:

[image]

### Algorithm

#### Notation

$\bar{t}_{q}$: target (vector) of $q$th input training point

$\bar{a}_{q}$: network output (vector) for $q$th input training point

$E_{D} = \sum\,\left(\bar{t}_{q}-\bar{a}_{q}\right)^{2}$ (sum squared error)

$E_{W}$ = $\sum\,\omega_{i}^{2}$ sum of squared network weights

$\gamma = n - 2\alpha\,\texttt{trace}\left(H^{-1}\right)$, this is the "effective number of parameters". $H$ is the (approximated) Hessian matrix of $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)$ (see below).

$\alpha = \frac{\gamma}{2E_{W}}$

$\beta = \frac{N-\gamma}{2E_{D}}$

$F\left(\bar{\omega}\right) = \beta\,E_{D} + \alpha\,E_{W}$ regularised objective function, with penalty for large weights $\bar{\omega}$

#### Schema

I implemented the algorithm as follows:

1. Initialize the network weights $\omega_{i}$ randomly, calculate $E_{D}$ and $E_{W}$, set $\gamma$ to $n$ and compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as above
2. Take a step in the Levenberg-Marquard algorithm towards minimizing $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)$.
3. Compute $\gamma$ with the new values for $E_{D}$ and $E_{W}$ (using the newly calculated weights $\bar{\omega}$).
4. Compute new values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, using the new values for $\gamma$, $E_{D}$ and $E_{W}$.
5. Iterate step 2-4 until converge

I am trying to apply this algorithm to a function $1+\texttt{sin}\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\,x\right) + \epsilon$, where I take only 21 evenly distributed points on $[-2, 2]$ where $\epsilon$ is a random number from a gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $0.25$ (like in the book).

#### Jacobian

To calculate the Jacobian for $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)=\beta\,E_{D}+\alpha\,E_{W}$ (in stead of for $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)=E_{D}$), I made the following modifications to the non-regularised code:

I heeded the assumption that for the Levenberg-Marquard algorithm to work, the general shape of $F\left(\bar{\omega}\right)$ must be a sum of squares: $\sum\,v^{2}_{i}$.

So for the $E_{D}$ part, the $v^{\texttt{new}}_{i}$ become $\sqrt{\beta}v^{\texttt{old}}_{i}$. And for the $E_{W}$ part, the $v_{i}$ become $\sqrt{\alpha}\omega_{i}$.

Hence, the "old" elements of the Jacobian $\left(\frac{\partial\,v_{i}}{\partial\,\omega_{j}}\right)$ are multiplied by $\sqrt{\beta}$.

Also, the Jacobian becomes much bigger now to include the $E_{W}$ part. A row is added for each weight in the network, with terms $\frac{\partial\,v_{i}}{\partial\,\omega_{j}}$, which are zero when $i=j$ and otherwise $\sqrt{\alpha}$.